# How do I build a sum() query in Laravel with the add and subtract operators?

Tags: mysql, laravel

so I have a query as such;

```
select sum(points_add) as total_add, sum(points_subtract) as total_deducts, (sum(points_add)-sum(points_subtract)) as total_balance from tbl_points where user_id = 2;
```

How do I build it in Laravel? I know how to do it up until the `(sum(points_add)-sum(points_subtract)) as total_balance part` as I'm not sure how to query out the **"-"** subtract function.

Comment: I would guess you need to use raw expressions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: As already mentioned, seems like raw expressions are the way to go. Are `points_add` and `points_substract` columns in your points table?

Comment: looking into it at the moment. and yeah, in my points table I have these columns; `user_id`, `points_add`, `points_subtract`, `points_total`. basically before i calculate any points, i want to get the user's cumulative `points_add`  and subtract it with his/her cumulative `points_subtract` to know their available points.

Comment: would it be better to use a stored procedure and just execute it via laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this the easiest thing would be to use [selectRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-methods):

```
$values = DB::table('tbl_points')
    ->selectRaw('sum(points_add) as total_add, sum(points_subtract) as total_deducts, (sum(points_add)-sum(points_subtract)) as total_balance')
    ->where('user_id', 2)
    ->first();
```

Laravel does come with [aggregates()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#aggregates), however, these are used to return single values instead of multiple aggregates.